# Pagination showing 4 ways instead of only 1 (default one)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a `Laravel project` and when I used `pagination` with `links() method`, it showed in the page 3-4 methods of pagination (all of them are working good), but I want to show only one of them. I haven't modified anything like `CSS or JS`, but I don't know how to get only one out of 4 of them. This is my pagination section:
[image: Page view on pagination section]

Comment: try using toArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your **App Service Provider:**

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

---

Here is documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#using-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks man. I was using this function inside my PostsController and now that I moved it inside App Service Provider I got my paginator as I wanted it to be. Cheers